# trouble with section headers in UITableView

Tags: iphone

im having a problem with setting my section headers in a uitableview, its probably something really simple i just cant work it out.

instead of displaying different headers for different sections it displays the same header for each section

help me please :)

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    WorldCupAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    return [appDelegate.matchFixtures count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    WorldCupAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    Fixtures *fixtures = [appDelegate.matchFixtures objectAtIndex:section];

    return fixtures.matchDate;

}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see that appDelegate.matchFixtures count has any value by printing via NSLog?.  Same for fixtures.matchDate?

Comment: Does every matchFixture have a different matchDate?

Answer (score 3):

Your original code looks okay.  I'm betting that appDelegate.matchFixtures doesn't contain the data you think it does.  Modify your code to look like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  WorldCupAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

  NSLog(@"appDelegate.matchFixtures.count = %i", appDelegate.matchFixtures.count);

  return [appDelegate.matchFixtures count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  WorldCupAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
  Fixtures *fixtures = [appDelegate.matchFixtures objectAtIndex:section];

  NSLog(@"For section %i, fixtures.matchDate = %@", section, fixtures.matchDate);

  return fixtures.matchDate;
}
```

And look at the log output in the debug console.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:      (NSInteger)section {
NSString *title = nil;
// Return a title or nil as appropriate for the section.
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        title = [[appDelegate.matchFixtures objectAtIndex:section]matchDate];
        break;
    case 1:
        title = [[appDelegate.matchFixtures objectAtIndex:section]matchDate];
        break;
    case 2:
        title = [[appDelegate.matchFixtures objectAtIndex:section]matchDate];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return title;
 }
```

Edit

Set the date properly with retain in the delegate class.Even i had some problems similar when storing values in delegates.

```
- (void)setCurrentDates:(NSString *)value {
[value retain]; // <- Retain new value
[date release]; // <- Release old value;
date = value;
}
```

All the best.

Comment: that looks about right , but it crashes my app 
with

2010-04-29 14:25:51.729 WorldCup[4912:207] *** -[Fixtures length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b0fe30
2010-04-29 14:25:51.730 WorldCup[4912:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[Fixtures length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b0fe30'
2010-04-29 14:25:51.731 WorldCup[4912:207] Stack: (

any ideas why?

Comment: print and check any one date value getting from the delegate

Comment: Based on the code in your question, the code in this answer should read case 0:
        title = [[appDelegate.matchFixtures objectAtIndex:section] matchDate];

Comment: thanks for all your help , unfortunatly i still couldn't get it working , so have gone a different way around it